# Can I class academic experience as relevant experience?

Tags: software-industry

Can I class academic or personal project experience as relevant experience ? What does comes under relevant experience in this context,

> Senior developer employed by a qualifying company, where the job
>   requires a person with a minimum of five years’ relevant experience
>   and demonstrable experience of having led a team

[Reference Page 5 of 14](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/486107/Shortage_Occupation_List_-_November_2015.pdf)

I have been at this company for 4 years and 6 months but I have experience of coding in university including final year project all coded by myself.

Can I class academic experience as relevant experience ?

Also what does `demonstrable experience` means in above context ? Is it related to duration or just proving it regardless of time.

Comment: I would suggest skipping classing academic experience as professional experience. Also it says demonstrable experience of having led a team. It means not the whole 5 years but i would say at least 2 years out of that. It should mean guided, mentored team members and optionally done appraisal work.

Comment: You cannot classify your experience as 5 years, it is up to the relevant HR to determine if you meet their criteria. What you do is try to sell them on the experience you have in your resume by presenting it in the best light possible. You are close enough to 5 years that it is probably worth it to apply if you are strong in all the other requirements particularly in this case the team lead experience. Some HRs will go for that and some won't but you have a 0% chance of being selected for interview if you don't apply. A lot depends on who else applied and what their qualifications were.

Comment: @HLGEM Thanks for your comment, I am not applying for a job but for a visa as referred in the given reference :)

Answer (score 4):

When a position description proscribes a minimum time frame, it's not normally a hard and fast rule.  Five years would be more of a guideline, so if you have *almost* five years of solid experience, then that very likely will be taken into consideration.

The academic experience could possibly be classified under *"Other Experience"*, but probably won't carry the same weight as your professional experience.  As a hiring manager, that to me is just part of getting your degree, not paid work in the field.

*Demonstrable experience* simply means you can back it your claimed work experience with the relevant professional work history and appropriate references.

Comment: I've typically seen the experience requirement broken down as follows: entry level (no experience), 1-2 years experience, 3-5 years experience and 5+.